# Getting update from UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

Can someone tell me how can I have a feature in my UserControl, that can let the host windowsform know what is the control is doing?

For example my usercontrol has a filebrowser, and if user uses this file browser to open a file I want in the statusstrip bar of my form to write "Loading file(s)".

Will this require using events? if so, how can I have a single event inside usercontrol to report anything it does (then I guess I have to call this event in all methods in the usercontrol).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to create an event and subscribe to it. One suggestion following the standard pattern for events:

```
enum ControlStatus {Idle, LoadingFile, ...}

class StatusChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ControlStatus Status {get; private set;}

    public StatusChangedEventArgs(ControlStatus status)
        : base()
    {
        this.Status = status;
    }
}

partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public ControlStatus Status {get; private set;}

    public event EventHandler<StatusChangedEventArgs> StatusChanged;

    protected virtual void OnStatusChanged(StatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var hand = StatusChanged;
        if(hand != null) hand(this, e);
    }

    void LoadFiles()
    {
        ...

        Status = ControlStatus.LoadingFiles; 
        OnStatusChanged(new StatusChangedEventArgs(this.Status));

        ...

        Status = ControlStatus.Idle; 
        OnStatusChanged(new StatusChangedEventArgs(this.Status));
    }
}

partial class MyHostWindowsForm : Form
{
    public MyHostWindowsForm()
    {
        var ctl = new MyControl();
        ...
        ctl.StatusChanged += ctl_StatusChanged;
    }

    void ctl_StatusChanged(object sender, StatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch(e.Status)
        {
            case ControlStatus.Idle:
                statusStripBar.Text = null;
                break;
            case ControlStatus.LoadingFiles:
                statusStripBar.Text = "Loading file(s)";
                break;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Simple**

Yes, expose an event on the user control that the Form can subscribe to. You should use the standard event pattern:

```
class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> FileOpened;

    protected virtual void OnFileOpened(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<EventArgs> handler = FileOpened;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

Then when the file is opened you call `OnFileOpened(EventArgs.Empty)` which fires the event.

**With custom EventArgs**

Now the Form probably needs to know what file was opened. You could expose a property on the user control that the Form can use to find out, or you can provide that information in your event like so:

```
public class FileOpenedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private string filename;
    public FileOpenedEventArgs(string filename)
    {
        this.filename = filename;
    }
    public string Filename { get { return filename; } }
}

class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler<FileOpenedEventArgs> FileOpened;

    protected virtual void OnFileOpened(FileOpenedEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<FileOpenedEventArgs> handler = FileOpened;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

Then you fire the event with `OnFileOpened(new FileOpenedEventArgs(filename))`.

**Optimal**

When you create an event handler `public event delegate Name;`, you are allocating storage for the delegate on your object. Objects (especially Controls) often have a huge number of events that are never subscribed to. That's a whole lot of allocated storage not being used. There's an optimization built into the framework in the form of a [EventHandlerList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.eventhandlerlist.aspx). This handy object stores event handlers only when they are actually used. All `System.Windows.Forms.Control` objects derive from `System.ComponentModel.Component` and it already provides an (protected) EventHandlerList that you can access in your derived Control.

To use it, you first create a static object that uniquely identifies your event, and then you provide the `add {}` and `remove {}` methods manually. Like so:

```
class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    private static readonly object FileOpenedKey = new Object();
    public event EventHandler<FileOpenedEventArgs> FileOpened
    {
        add { Events.AddHandler(FileOpenedKey, value); }
        remove { Events.RemoveHandler(FileOpenedKey, value); }
    }

    protected virtual void OnFileOpened(FileOpenedEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = (EventHandler<FileOpenedEventArgs>)Events[FileOpenedKey];
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);
    }
}
```